# a problem about a function __gethostbyname_r in the source file of gethostbyname

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I'm a new programer.When I try to read the source file of gethostbyname() in getXXbyYY.c,glibc , I found a function about macro.

```
INTERNAL (REENTRANT_NAME) (ADD_VARIABLES, &resbuf, buffer,buffer_size, &result H_ERRNO_VAR)
```

It can be resolved by following macros to be `__gethostbyname_r()`.

```
#define REENTRANT_NAME APPEND_R (FUNCTION_NAME)
#define APPEND_R(name) APPEND_R1 (name)
#define APPEND_R1(name) name##_r
#define INTERNAL(name) INTERNAL1 (name)
#define INTERNAL1(name) __##name
```

Then I try to find the implementation of `__gethostbyname_r()`, but I just found the prototype in `netdb.h`.

So, I want to know where is the implementation of `__gethostbyname_r()` and what will it do ?

Comment: It's probably defined using similar macros. Just look for `gethostbyname_r`(without the double leading underscore) and see what you find.

Answer (score 1):

With `libc6-dbg` package installed:

```
gdb /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

(gdb) info func __gethostbyname_r
All functions matching regular expression "__gethostbyname_r":

File ../nss/getXXbyYY_r.c:
188:    int __gethostbyname_r(const char *, struct hostent *, char *, size_t, struct hostent **, int *);
```

This tells you that you should look in `$GLIBC_SRC/nss/getXXbyYY_r.c` file, around line 188.

Comment: Also look in `$GLIBC_SRC/inet/gethstbynm_r.c` to see the external macro expansions used by `#include "../nss/getXXbyYY_r.c"`.